# Find the Derivative of an Inverse Function on Some Open Set

Tags: real-analysis

I am posed with the following question:
Let $f(u, v) = (3u − v, u + 4v).$ Fix $(x_0, y_0) ∈ \mathbb{R}^2$. Prove that $f^{−1}$ exists and is differentiable on some nonempty open set containing $(x_0,y_0)$ and compute the derivative there.

I'm a bit confused by this. If the set containing $(x_0,y_0)$ is $V$, shouldn't I be concerned with whether $f^{−1}$ exists and is differentiable on $f(V)$, which contains $f(x_0,y_0)$? Moreover, wouldn't I want to compute the derivative of $f^{−1}$ at $f(x_0,y_0)$? Did my instructor make a mistake or am I missing something?

Comment: They did it correctly. They mean find the inverse function $f^{-1}$ explicitly first then calculate it's derivative near $(x_0,y_0)$.

Comment: @CyclotomicField I don't understand how you can calculate the derivative of $f^{-1}$ near $(x_0,y_0)$ since this is not in the domain of $f^{-1}$.

Comment: The domain of both $f$ and $f^{-1}$ is $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: That makes sense, but the way my instructor solves this is by using the implicit function theorem. He notes that since $Df(x_0, y_0)$ is invertible, $f$ has an inverse in a neighborhood of $(x_0, y_0)$. He then calculates the derivative of $f^{-1}$ by inverting the matrix $Df(x_0, y_0)$. It would seem then that he wants us to really calculate $Df^{-1}(f(x_0, y_0))$ rather than $Df^{-1}(x_0, y_0)$, right?

Comment: Inverse function theorem* sorry

Comment: Firstly note that $f^{-1}(f(x_0,y_0))=(x_0,y_0)$ which is the identity function. You don't want calculate that. I think you're just a little confused because the domain is the same for both $f$ and $f^{-1}$. Seperate the domain of $f$ from the domain of $f^{-1}$ notationally by using different letters. So instead of $f(x_0,y_0)$ write $f(u_0,v_0)=(x_0,y_0)$  This makes it clear that $(x_0,y_0)$ is in the domain of $f^{-1}$ rather than $f$. What you really want to calculate is $Df^{-1}(x_0,y_0)$. I would also encourage you to find $f^{-1}$ and compare it with $Df^{-1}$ as well.